# All files under Home folder are write protected by unknown username

Tags: permissions

Using Ubuntu 16.04, I gave all the permission of my home folder to an unknown username and now I am unable to write to the files under my home folder including Documents, Downloads etc...

How do I give back permission to the current user account?

Comment: what exactly did you do to cause the problem?

Comment: When i tried to give permission of Apache server to Wordpress to create directory in \var\www\html  .

Comment: What *exactly* did you do to change the ownership of the home directory? What does `/var/www/html` (mind the slash direction!) have to do with your user account's home directory. Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @devius: No. This question is about **ownership** while your linked question is about **access control flags**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the ownership of a directory recursively run

```
sudo chown -R USER: PATH
```

and replace `USER` with the user name and `PATH` with the path of the directory tree in question (here: the home directory).